# Error when when generating Doxygen documentation with the Doxygen maven plugin

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, doxygen

I am trying to use the Maven Doxygen Plugin. I added that in the pom.xml of my project:

```
<reporting>
    <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.sf.doodleproject</groupId>
                <artifactId>doxygen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
</reporting>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>doodleproject-repo</id>
            <name>DoodleProject Maven 2 Repository</name>
            <url>http://doodleproject.sourceforge.net/maven2/release</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
        </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

And I launch the command:

```
mvn -X net.sf.doodleproject:doxygen-maven-plugin:report
```

And I have this error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal net.sf.doodleproject:doxygen-maven-plugin:2.2:report (default-cli) on project project: An error has occurred in Doxygen report generation.               
    Failed to generate Doxygen documentation. -> [Help 1] org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: 
    Failed to execute goal net.sf.doodleproject:doxygen-maven-plugin:2.2:report (default-cli) on project amc: An error has occurred in Doxygen report generation.

            at    org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)

    Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: An error has occurred in Doxygen report generation.
        at org.apache.maven.reporting.AbstractMavenReport.execute(AbstractMavenReport.java:83)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)

    Caused by: org.apache.maven.reporting.MavenReportException: Failed to generate Doxygen documentation.
        at net.sf.doodleproject.mavenite.doxygen.DoxygenReport.executeReport(DoxygenReport.java:299)
        at org.apache.maven.reporting.AbstractMavenReport.generate(AbstractMavenReport.java:131)
```

Doxygen is working well when I use it on my project without the maven plugin.
There is something else to do to use the plugin?

Thanks for your help,

Answer (score 0):

I tried with another plugin: com.soebes.maven.plugins.dmg and it's working.

My pom.xml:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.soebes.maven.plugins.dmg</groupId>
                    <artifactId>doxygen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                            <projectName>${project.artifactId}</projectName>
                            <projectNumber>${project.version}</projectNumber>
                            <optimizeOutputJava>true</optimizeOutputJava>
                        <extractAll>true</extractAll>
                            <extractStatic>true</extractStatic>
                            <recursive>true</recursive>
                            <exclude>.git</exclude>
                            <recursive>true</recursive>
                            <umlLook>true</umlLook>
                            <haveGraph>true</haveGraph>
                            <generateLatex>false</generateLatex>
                            <generateHtml>true</generateHtml>
                            <outputDirectory>${basedir}/doxygen_doc</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>doodleproject-repo</id>
        <name>DoodleProject Maven 2 Repository</name>
        <url>http://doodleproject.sourceforge.net/maven2/release</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this plugin. Worked great for me:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <failOnError>false</failOnError>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: The question was about Doxygen, not about Javadoc. Different tools.